# jenkins clean workspace plugin can't delete binary files from workspace

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

jenkins clean workspace plugin can't delete binary file from workspace. Manually clean up required in this automated world. Any Idea how can it be deleted automatic?

```
Deleting project workspace... 
done

Cleaning local Directory .

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete /local/hudson/workspace/north_gate/./ilt/ilt_dom_tc/patch/tod.tar.gz
```

Comment: Permission issue? What are the permissions list with `ls -l` command on that file?

Comment: the permission is 755 and ilt is the owner which should delete it but it is not.